# Unable to output the longest string

Tags: c

Problem Statement: write a program that reads a set of text lines and prints the longest.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int getlinetext(char s[]);

int main(void)
{
    char longest[MAX];
    int longestlenght = 0;
    char line[MAX];
    int lenght;

    while ((lenght = getlinetext(line)) > 0){
        if(lenght > longestlenght){
            longestlenght = lenght;
            int i = 0;
            while (line[i] != '\0'){
                longest[i] = line[i];
                i++;
            }
            longest[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf("The longest lenght is %d\n", longestlenght);
    printf("%s\n", longest); 
    return 0;
}

int getlinetext(char line[])
{
    int i=0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        line[i] == c;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
hello
world!!
The longest lenght is 7
world!!
```

Actual Output:

```
hello
world!!
The longest lenght is 7
�
```

Somehow, I am able to print the correct longest lenght but not the string itself. I thought I miss the null byte, but it's there and the error still persist.

Comment: please provide input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: It's less than 100 characters.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: `line[i] == c;` --> `line[i] = c;`

Comment: UV for a well presented post, even though a simple error.  Insure compiler warnings are fully enabled, saves you time - that is how I caught it.

Comment: @chux Right. I am embarrassed for the stupid mistake.
Anyway, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PriyankChheda This is still appearing as an "unanswered" question. Please post a brief answer and accept it.

Comment: Also for readability , lenght -> length, like everywhere, it might pain eye when you put this code in production and then someone else sees this after a bit, so you might wanna change it everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chux pointed out, i made a silly mistake by using equal sign ("==") instead of assignment sign ("=") on line #34:

```
line[i] == c -> line[i] = c
```

So the corrected program would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int getlinetext(char s[]);

int main(void)
{
    char longest[MAX];
    int longestlenght = 0;
    char line[MAX];
    int lenght;

    while ((lenght = getlinetext(line)) > 0){
        if(lenght > longestlenght){
            longestlenght = lenght;
            int i = 0;
            while (line[i] != '\0'){
                longest[i] = line[i];
                i++;
            }
            longest[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf("The longest lenght is %d\n", longestlenght);
    printf("%s\n", longest); 
    return 0;
}

int getlinetext(char line[])
{
    int i=0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        line[i] = c;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: It won't be the last time you make that mistake (but your compiler should be warning you about it) `:)` Also `lenght` is actually spelled `length` (that makes no difference to your code, but it looks wonky...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin @chux I am using gcc on linux. And for compilation, I used `gcc -o test test.c`. gcc never gave me any warning.

Comment: You should be using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -o test test.c` if you want all warnings add `-pedantic`, if you want full optimization use `-Ofast` (available **gcc >= 4.6**, before use `-O3`). Optimized code can run several hundred percent faster. The `-Wall -Wextra` will enable warnings and you should resolve all warnings before you consider you code reliable. The warnings are actually quite well written, after you work with then a while...

Comment: Wow...That's a load of information. Thanks a lot.
i wish i could upvote your comment.

Comment: You might need a reputation of 20 before you can upvote comments, you will get there. Good luck with your coding. I would also encourage leaving a space between function names and the `(` (e.g. `printf (...`), as well as control statements (e.g. `if (...`). You will find that makes code easier to read (especially as you age and your eyes are not what they once were....